# How to debug write conflict error in mongo DB transactions

Tags: mongodb, spring-webflux

I'm using mongo DB with spring webflux. I'm getting the following error randomly inside a transaction:

`Command failed with error 112 (WriteConflict): 'WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.'`

My function is a large one where I'm doing a lot of read and writes. I understand that there are conflicts due to race condition. But how can I know which DB operation triggered this error?